# Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. But I don`t have async functions

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-redux

I am really confused!!

So, I wand to dispatch another action inside of action:

```
import * as actionsTypes from '../constants/actionsTypes';

export const loginUserSuccess = userName => ({
  type: actionsTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  userName
});

export const loginUserFailed = () => ({
  type: actionsTypes.LOGIN_FAILED
});

export const loginUser = userName => dispatch => {
  dispatch(loginUserSuccess(userName));
}
```

Inside of loginUser action I will create a logic to choose which action to dispatch. It is doesn`t matter for now

Here is usage of loginUser action

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { loginUser } from '../../actions';

class loginUserForm extends Component {
  state = {
    userName: ''
  }

  inputChangeHandler = event => {
    this.setState({ userName: event.target.value })
  }

  loginUserHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.loginUser(this.state.userName);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form className="login-user" onSubmit={event => this.loginUserHandler(event)}>
        <input type="text" onChange={event => this.inputChangeHandler(event)} />
        <input type="submit" value="Login" disabled={this.state.userName.length === 0} />
      </form>
    )
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  loginUser: userName => dispatch(loginUser(userName))
})
```

Nothing super-natural :) But!! I have an error

> Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async
>   actions.

This is really fun! I don`t have an async code here!!

What a hell is going on...

Comment: Hi @Yaroslav Melnychuk, welcome to Stackoverflow, could you explain better what do you mean with dispatch an action inside another action?

Comment: Hi, @vitomadio. Look. I have loginUser. This is an action. Inside of it i will create some logic to choose which action to dispatch. loginUserFailed of loginUserSuccess. Inside of my reducer I have a switch/case which checks between LOGIN_SUCCESS and LOGIN_FAILED action types. And depends on it I change my state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`loginUser()` is a "thunk".  That means that it's actually passing a function to the real `store.dispatch()`, and is not a plain action object.

Make sure that you've actually included the `redux-thunk` middleware as part of your store setup process - that teaches the store to accept passing functions to `store.dispatch()`.  See the posts [What the heck is a "thunk"?](https://daveceddia.com/what-is-a-thunk/) and [Thunks in Redux: The Basics](https://medium.com/fullstack-academy/thunks-in-redux-the-basics-85e538a3fe60) for explanations on what this means.

Also, as a side note, you can simplify that file a bit.  `connect` supports an "object shorthand" for defining `mapDispatch` - you can pass an object full of action creators directly, like:

```
const mapDispatch = {loginUser};
```

Comment: Thank u so much for explanation! I`ve just thought that redux-thunk is using only when we have requests to API or other async code and thought that it is redundantly to use it here. And thanks for note about mapDispatchToProps  :)

Comment: Thunks are actually good for several different uses.  See the [new Redux FAQ entry on choosing thunks vs other async middleware](https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#what-async-middleware-should-i-use-how-do-you-decide-between-thunks-sagas-observables-or-something-else), and [this gist of thunk examples](https://gist.github.com/markerikson/ea4d0a6ce56ee479fe8b356e099f857e).

Comment: One other suggestion. We've got a work-in-progress library called [`redux-starter-kit`](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-starter-kit), which makes it easier to set up your store and write reducers.  As part of that, it automatically adds `redux-thunk` to your store by default.  I'd encourage you to try it out and see if that makes using Redux easier.